# Big Commerce Custom Fields

Tags: field, product, bigcommerce

I'm planning on allowing a client to provide a couple codes for each product that I'll need to reference with Javascript on the product pages.

Basically my plan was to use the Big Commerce's 'custom fields' to do so, but I'm having trouble spitting out the custom fields onto the product pages. I've been looking all over for some type of GLOBAL variable that allows me to reference custom fields, but I'm coming up dry. I would think there would be some type of GLOBAL array with all the custom fields in it, or a way to reference them by name directly.

Am I blind, or is there just no way to do this directly in the BC template file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bigcommerce the custom fields can generally be found within the `ProductOtherDetails.html` Panel which contains a Snippet named `ProductCustomFieldItem.html`. This snippet has the markup for each custom field that the system outputs.

Inside of the ProductCustomFieldItem.html Snippet are the two codes you are looking for: `%%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%` and `%%GLOBAL_CustomFieldValue%%`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well - given that it's quite a long time later, I'm supposing there's no better answer - a decent amount of searching turned up nothing useful as it seems all you can do is output the full set of custom fields as a set of divs.

So, I output them into a div which was hidden:

```
<div id="fpd-custom-fields" style="display:none;">
    %%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFields%%
</div>
```

and then set up a javascript function to get the value based on the name:

```
function getCustomFieldValue(label)
{
    var value = '';

    $('#fpd-custom-fields div.Label').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == (label.toLowerCase() + ':'))
        {
            value = $('div.Value', $(this).parent()).text().trim();
        }
    });

    return value;
}
```

Doesn't feel quite right as it's not a very clean solution, but was the best I could come up with unfortunately!

Comment: I forgot to follow up on this post. Yeah, both of you are correct in that the only place you can reference them is the product custom fields snippet. The solution I ended up using was far from clean as well. Just doesn't seem there's a 'clean' way to do it within BC.